# Apache Spark: Yarn logs Analysis

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, logstash, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I am having a spark-streaming application, and I want to analyse the logs of the job using Elasticsearch-Kibana. My job is run on yarn cluster, so the logs are getting written to HDFS as I have set `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` to true. But, when I try to do this :

`hadoop fs -cat ${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}/${user.name}/logs/<application ID>`

I am seeing some encrypted/compressed data. What file format is this? How can I read the logs from this file? Can I use logstash to read this?

Also, if there is a better approach to analyse Spark logs, I am open to your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try using -text instead of -cat? hadoop fs -text ...

Comment: Tried that. Still the same result.

Comment: Just want to know if there's any API for converting this type of file to text file.. Yarn logs does it anyway right

Answer (score 3):

The format is called a [**TFile**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/file/tfile/TFile.html), and it is a compressed file format.

> Yarn however chooses to write the application logs into a TFile!! For those of you who don’t know what a TFile is (and I bet a lot of you don’t), you can learn more about it here, but for now this basic definition should suffice “A TFile is a container of key-value pairs. Both keys and values are type-less bytes”.

[Splunk / Hadoop Rant](https://www.splunk.com/blog/2013/11/18/hadoop-2-0-rant/)

There may be a way to edit YARN and Spark's `log4j.properties` to [send messages to Logstash using SocketAppender](https://tech-stories.com/2015/02/12/setting-up-a-central-logging-infrastructure-for-hadoop-and-spark/)

However, [that method is being deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/log4j-input-logstash)