# HDP 2.4, How to collect hadoop mapreduce log using flume in one file and what is the best practice

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce, bigdata

We are using HDP 2.4 and have many map reduce jobs written in various ways ( java MR / Hive / etc. ) . The logs are collect in hadoop file system under the application ID. I want to collect all the logs of application and append in single file (hdfs or OS files of one machine) so that I can analyze my application log in a single location with out hassle . Also advise me the best way to achieve in HDP 2.4 ( Stack version info => HDFS    2.7.1.2.4 / YARN    2.7.1.2.4 / MapReduce2  2.7.1.2.4 / Log Search  0.5.0 / Flume   1.5.2.2.4 ) .

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797255/log4j-rollingfileappender-not-adding-mapper-and-reducer-logs-to-file#autocomment86725314

Answer (score 0):

Flume cannot collect the logs after they are already on HDFS.

In order to do this, you need a Flume agent running on all NodeManagers pointed at the configured `yarn.log.dir`, and somehow parse out the application/container/attempt/file information from the local OS file path.

I'm not sure how well collecting into a "single file" would work, as each container generates at least 5 files of different information, but YARN log aggregation already does this. It's just [not in a readable file format in HDFS unless you are using Splunk/Hunk, as far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44271583/2308683)

Alternative solutions include indexing these files into actual search services like Solr or Elasticsearch, which I would  recommend for storing and searching logs over HDFS