# Log4j RollingFileAppender not adding mapper and reducer logs to file

Tags: hadoop, logging, mapreduce, log4j, hortonworks-data-platform

We would like our application logs to be printed to files on the local nodes. We're using Log4j's RollingFileAppender.

Our `log4j.properties` file is as follows:

```
ODS.LOG.DIR=/var/log/appLogs
ODS.LOG.INFO.FILE=application.log
ODS.LOG.ERROR.FILE=application_error.log
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, console
log4j.logger.com.ournamespace=ERROR, APP_APPENDER, ERROR_APPENDER

#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{5}: %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.File=${ODS.LOG.DIR}/${ODS.LOG.INFO.FILE}
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.APP_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{10}: %m%n


log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.File=${ODS.LOG.DIR}/${ODS.LOG.ERROR.FILE}
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=200MB
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=90
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERROR_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}-%r %p %c{10}: %m%n
```

Our MR Driver logs are appearing in `/var/log/appLogs` directory but our mapper and reducer logs dont show up in this directory.

We have copied our log4j.properties snippet to hdfs-log4j, yarn-log4j, hbase-log4j and zookeeper-log4j using Ambari (Hortonworks Data Platform). Our MR jobs typically use HBase input and output format classes.

**What changes do we need to make to have the mapper and reducer logs appear in the /var/log/appLogs directory as well?**

Edit: The logs are appearing in the JobHistory UI `syslog` but they aren't being added to the log file. What are we missing?

Comment: This seems to be related to a post [HDP 2.4, How to collect hadoop mapreduce log using flume in one file and what is the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789992/hdp-2-4-how-to-collect-hadoop-mapreduce-log-using-flume-in-one-file-and-what-is/49796878#49796878)

Comment: Would appreciate if someone could provide some insights into why the mapper and reducer logs aren't showing in the file

Answer (score 0):

For example to configure log4j you can call  `PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);` from your code e.g. in mapper/reducer setup method.

This is example with properties stored on hdfs:

```
        InputStream is = fs.open(log4jPropertiesPath);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(is);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
```

where fs is FileSystem object and log4jPropertiesPath is path on hdfs.

Comment: any way we dont have to do this manually in our classes? We have thousands of classes and this code would be difficult to add in all of them

Comment: We have base mapper/reducer and our mappers/reducers extend those base classes

Comment: @Luk: i had tried this solution, put log4j properties file in hdfs, and tried your code snippet in mapper/reducer setup method but still mapper/reducer logs not coming.

Comment: What is your problem? You have to be more specific, so I can reproduce the problem and help you. This is the code we are using in our system and works perfectly well.

Comment: Hi @Luk, the issue is that we can see the logs in the syslogs using JobHistory UI but we need all the logs of all mappers + all reducers (on a single node) to be written to a single file on the node. That is not happening with your solution as we dont see any logs being written to the log file